# Python Как узнать кому принадлежит объект через метод этого объекта

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, объекты

Пример: есть объект ***Персона***, у которого есть объект ***Голова***.

У ***Головы*** есть метод `who_my_owner()`, который должен возвращать ***Персону***, кому она принадлежит.

Можно, конечно, использовать уникальные идентификаторы, чтобы при создании головы, ей сообщался ***id*** хозяина. Но есть ли другой способ, чтобы уместить его в один метод `who_my_owner()` и без дополнительных манипуляций с остальным кодом?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Head()

class Head:
    def who_my_owner(self):
        pass

pers1 = Person()
pers2 = Person()
pers3 = pers1.head.who_my_owner() #должно быть эквивалентно pers3 = pers1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Head(self)

class Head():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

    def who_my_owner(self):
#        pass
        return self.parent

pers1 = Person()
print(f"pers1 - {pers1}")
pers2 = Person()
pers3 = pers1.head.who_my_owner() #должно быть эквивалентно pers3 = pers1
print(f"pers3 - {pers3}")
```

**pers1** - <**main**.Person object at 0x0000000002378B70>

**pers3** - <**main**.Person object at 0x0000000002378B70>